# Simple form using functions not working in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am working with functions for the first time, and trying to create a simple BMI calculator that displays a BMI value and the corresponding category with a message box. While Visual Basic does not indicate any problems with my code, nothing happens when I click the button on the form. Due to the fact that VB isn't giving me any hints as to what the problem is, I have no idea where to start looking.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim height As Double = TextBox1.Text
        Dim weight As Double = TextBox2.Text
    End Sub
    Function Bmicalc(ByVal height As Double, ByVal weight As Double) As Double
        Dim bmi As Double
        bmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703
        Bmicalc = bmi
        Return bmi
    End Function
    Function bmiCategory(ByVal bmi As Double, ByVal category As String) As String
        If bmi < 18.5 Then
            category = "Underweight"
        ElseIf bmi >= 18.5 And bmi > 25 Then
            category = "Normal"
        ElseIf bmi >= 25 And bmi < 30 Then
            category = "Overweight"
        ElseIf bmi > 30 Then
            category = "Obese"
        End If
        bmiCategory = category
        Return category
        MessageBox.Show("Your bmi is: " & "" & bmi & "The category is: " & "" & category)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Your Button1_Click event (the only thing defined as a handler) does nothing more than define two local variables and then ends.

Comment: I understand that, and have since caught that, but I have no idea how to correct it. When I move the messagebox command into the button sub event, the bmi and category variables don't work. When I expand the event to include all of the code, it wants me to add an end sub before the first Function.

Comment: You need to give your variables Class level scope if you are going to use them in multiple methods.

Comment: "no compiler errors" does not mean flawless logic.

Comment: Your button click does not call any of your Functions.  Also, in your Bmicalc method, you can omit this line because it is not needed:  `Bmicalc = bmi`.   While it does not cause any problems, it is old style VB6 coding and is redundant.  Just the Return statement is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim height As Double = TextBox1.Text
    Dim weight As Double = TextBox2.Text
    Dim returnString as String
    returnString=bmiCategory(Bmicalc(height,weight),"")
End Sub
Function Bmicalc(ByVal height As Double, ByVal weight As Double) As Double
    Dim bmi As Double
    bmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703
    'if you want to return a value,just do it like below
    Return bmi
End Function
Function bmiCategory(ByVal bmi As Double, ByVal category As String) As String
    If bmi < 18.5 Then
        category = "Underweight"
    ElseIf bmi >= 18.5 And bmi > 25 Then
        category = "Normal"
    ElseIf bmi >= 25 And bmi < 30 Then
        category = "Overweight"
    ElseIf bmi > 30 Then
        category = "Obese"
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Your bmi is: " & "" & bmi & "The category is: " & "" & category)
    Return category'Notice here!
    End Function
   End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works as I need it to. I'm going to have to work with functions a bit more to wrap my head around how to write them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little suggestion and reflector of your code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'In the future, you should validate user input as well.
    Dim bmi As Double = BmiCalc(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
    Dim category As String = BmiCategory(bmi)

    'It's  better to have your message displayed at event instead of Funtion
    MessageBox.Show("Your bmi is: " & "" & bmi.ToString & "The category is: " & "" & category)
End Sub

Function BmiCalc(ByVal height As Double, ByVal weight As Double) As Double
    Dim bmi As Double = (weight / (height * height)) * 703
    Return bmi
    'OR Just 
    Return (weight / (height * height)) * 703
End Function

'Since you dont actually perform any action with variable Category, you dont need that.
'Just place a return for each condition.
'I assume you might wan to know about Select Case too.
Function BmiCategory(ByVal bmi As Double) As String
    If bmi < 18.5 Then
        Return "Underweight"
    ElseIf bmi >= 18.5 And bmi < 25 Then
        Return "Normal"
    ElseIf bmi >= 25 And bmi < 30 Then
        Return "Overweight"
    Else
        Return "Obese"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Functions` are pretty much the same as `Methods/Sub` (in VB.net) except the fact that they are Methods **that return values** (or object, or structure or Nothing, etc.) If you're familiar with C#, let's assume you only have *Functions* in C#, while C# *Methods* are the ones with the `void` keyword (no return type)

To have a meaning (in VB.Net) in most cases, you should assing the returning type of a Function to a variable of the same type :

```
    ' Block that calls the Function
    Dim myVar As Double = Bmicalc(height, weight) ' Bmicalc returns a Double..

    ' then use myVar as required 
    ' as it hosts the output value of Bmicalc previously called
    ' ...
    MessageBox.Show(myVar.ToString())
```

And you can use `Functions` like `Methods`, without assinging the output to a variable. There are some cases it's usefull.

---

### Bmicalc Function :

```
    Function Bmicalc(ByVal height As Double, ByVal weight As Double) As Double
        Dim bmi As Double
        bmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703
        ' Bmicalc = bmi : Remove this : not required.

        Return bmi ' this Function returns the value of bmi (Double)
    End Function
```

### bmiCategory Function :

```
    Function bmiCategory(ByVal bmi As Double) As String
        ' Remove the Category Paremeter declaration, 
        ' and move it inside this Function :

        Dim category As String

        If bmi < 18.5 Then
            category = "Underweight"
        ElseIf bmi >= 18.5 And bmi < 25 Then ' Beware : you had a typo here "> 25 !!!
            category = "Normal"
        ElseIf bmi >= 25 And bmi < 30 Then
            category = "Overweight"
        ElseIf bmi > 30 Then
            category = "Obese"
        End If

        ' bmiCategory = category <- Remove this : not required.

        Return category ' this Function returns the value of category

        ' MessageBox.Show("Your bmi is: " & "" & bmi & "The category is: " & "" & category)
        ' Remove the MessageBox : Functions are rarely usefull 
        ' when they constantly pop a DialogBox...
    End Function
```

### Button1

What your button should trigger upon click event :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim height As Double = TextBox1.Text ' get the height - OK
        Dim weight As Double = TextBox2.Text ' get the weight - OK

        ' Calculate bmi...
        Dim bmi As Double = Bmicalc(height, weight) ' OK

        ' format the result...
        Dim result As String = "Your bmi is: " & "" & bmi & "The category is: " & "" & bmiCategory(bmi)

        ' show the result...
        MessageBox.Show(result)

        ' Don't be used to mix core code (the Bmicalc and bmiCategory Functions)
        ' and user interface (The Button and the resulting DialogBox)
    End Sub
```

---

**Some points you should be aware of...**

1. What if I enter "lol" in `TextBox1.Text` ? When you create an application, you should assume the lambda user is a 2 years old kid... (or at least that's what was taught us in school), like checking if `TextBox1.Text` contains a *valid positive numeric literal*.. I could also enter a *negative number*, or select the content of TextBox1, hit "Delete" on the keyboard then click on Button1...

   ```
       Dim height As Double = TextBox1.Text ' <- "lol" throws an exception...
   ```
2. DotNet provides usefull conversions to the `String` type. You should use them anytime (I didn't apply this rule in the code above though, but you should) That's annoying I know, but this saved me many hours when I had to update applications I've made months or years back. Cleaner and self explanatory.

   ```
       bmi.ToString()
   ```
3. Divisions :

   ```
       bmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703
       ' what if heigth = 0
       ' You'll have a DivisionByZero Exception...
   ```
4. *"... While Visual Basic does not indicate any problems with my code ..."* I used to think the same until I added those at the top of each vb File content :

   ```
   Option Strict On
   Option Explicit On
   Option Infer Off

   Public Class Dummy
       ' ... blah blah blah
       ' ...
   ```
5. To make things easier, I use a prefix when I define `Functions` **in VB.net** : ***Get**blahblah*. (And here are reworked version of the Functions)

   ```
   Public Function GetBmi(ByVal Height As Double, ByVal Weight As Double) As Double
       If Height > 0 Then
           Return Math.Abs(Weight) * 703 / (Height * Height)
       Else
           Throw New ArgumentException("Negative or null Height is not allowed.")
       End If
   End Function

   Public Function GetCategory(ByVal Bmi As Double) As String
       Select Case True
           ' Pick one test in sequence and return a value if True...
           ' similar behaviour as If/ElseIf...EndIf
           Case bmi < 18.5:
               Return "Underweight"
           Case bmi < 25:
               Return "Normal"
           Case bmi < 30:
               Return "Overweight"
           Case Else:
               Return "Obese"
       End Select
       ' Note that you could have discard the lower bound test (ElseIf bmi >= 25)
       ' in your original If/ElseIf...End If block aswell.
   End Function
   ```
6. Functions that return `String`... You should be aware that String is a type that cost a lot for the CPU. What if you'll make your application multilingual ? You'll have to convert the *"Overweight"* output of `bmiCategory` Function to *"Surpoids"* for French culture for example... Better use Enums instead, you don't think ? like :

   ```
   Public Enum bmiLevel
       UnderWeight
       Normal
       OverWeight
       Obese
   End Enum

   ' and use one value of that enumeration as an output for bmiCategory
   Public Function bmiCategory(ByVal bmi As Double) As bmiLevel
       If bmi < 18.5 Then
           Return bmiLevel.UnderWeight
       ElseIf bmi < 25 Then
           Return bmiLevel.Normal
       ElseIf ' ....
           ' ....

   ' then depending on the value of category, 
   ' display the appropriate String value in the appropriate Culture
   ' somewhere in other part of your code, like in Button1.Click handling...
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       ' ...
       ' ...
       result = "Your bmi is: " & bmi.ToString() & " - The category is: "
       Select Case category
           Case bmiLevel.UnderWeight:
               result = result + "Underweight"
           Case bmiLevel.Normal:
               result = result + "Normal"
           ' ...
       End Select
       MessageBox.Show(result)
   End Sub
   ```
7. which leads me to the last point : *Are you sure StackOverflow (SO) could really help you ?* The purpose of SO is to help solving some really inconvenient issues that are sparsely documented, or even never tried before. You should take a look on the vb.Net documentation for a couple of things :

   - how Functions works in vb.Net ?
   - what the "Return" keyword does ?
   - does a code *after* a Return blahblah is executed ?

In most cases, SO doesn't give answers to questions which answers can easily be found by typing that very question in google...

Didn't meant to be rude or condescending, or look clever either, I'm relatively new to SO and just "average" level of programming. Some new SO users/members that are beeing flagged or downvoted doesn't understand the main goal of SO and end in thinking SO is for experts only... It's just about **efficiency** : Specific answers to specific questions. If a question requires an entire book for the answer to be "correct", the purpose of getting a working solution to a problem **with the fewest lines of code** is not fulfilled. SO wouldn't differ from the massive amount of blah blah out there on the web...